# Oracle APEX editable calendar

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need help with Oracle APEX calendar.
APEX version is 4.2.

Here's my task:

I need to store the employees holidays in a database. 
Employees should be able to plan their holidays on a calendar in an APEX application.

The needed use cases:

- employees can see on which days they planned to be on holiday
- employees can write the number of hours to a day in the calendar they 
  plan to take off.
  Then the edited calendars data is to be saved into the database.

My problem is, that Oracle APEX calendars only seem to be good for viewing an SQL query, but they cannot be edited, saved into the database.
How could I solve this problem? Is there an APEX plugin that is suitable for the mentioned use cases?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What version of APEX are you using, and if APEX 5 are you using the new-style calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APEX calendar displays data from whatever table(s) you choose in the form of a calendar.  To "edit the calendar" you need to insert, update or delete the data in the table(s) the calendar is based on.  The simplest way to do this is as follows:

### To create a new entry

Add a button "Create entry" to the page that navigates to another page where the user can enter a date and details for the new calendar entry.  Save this to the table and return to the calendar page - the new calendar entry will be displayed.

### To update/delete an existing entry

The calendar allows you to define a link for each calendar entry (look under Calendar Attributes).  This link can navigate to another page passing in data about the clicked calendar entry.  Set it up to navigate to a page where the user can edit or delete the calendar entry and save the change to the table. On return to the calendar page the calendar entry will have been updated or deleted.

That is the simplest approach.  You could improve on this, for example setting up a dynamic action to navigate to the create entry page when the user clicks in the empty space in a calendar cell.  That requires some knowledge of jQuery selectors, and maybe some Javascript.

You could also use a modal form instead of navigating away to a new page - in APEX 5.0 this is possible natively, for earlier versions you could use a third-party modal plug-in.